# Question relating topology to measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a general question.

In point set topology we say given a set $X$, we take $\tau$ to be the set of its subsets that we will call $\textit{open}$. So Then $(X,\tau)$ becomes a topological space where we say $U \in \tau$ if and only if $$(U \in \mathcal{P}(X)) \wedge (U \text{is open in} X)$$

In which case we can define $\tau$ to be standard on $\mathbb{R}$, cofinite, discreet, indiscreet, $p$-adic,ect.

In Real Analysis or more specifically in measure theory, I noticed that we are given a set $X$, a measure $\mu$ and then a sigma algebra $\sigma_X$ whose elements are $\mu-\textit{measurable}$. Is this correct? Then for any $E \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ can we say $E$ is $\mu - \textit{measurable}$ if and only if

$$E \in \sigma_X$$

Where $\sigma_X$ is closed under complements, countable union and intersection whereas $\tau$ is closed under arb union of open arb intersection of closed and finite union of closed and finite intersection of open? Then just as $\tau$ can be defined how one likes, can one define $\mu$ to be different than standard measure and thus elements of $\sigma_X$ would be different based on the measure introduced?

On this same note, do results such as MCT, DCT, BCT, Egorov all hold if we take different topologies on $\mathbb{R}$? On the same note do point set topology results such as compact subset of closed is closed hold if we swap the measure from standard measure? I know for example Heine Borel holds for standard topology only but that's from Topology to Topology I wanna see if changing assumption of one field rules out results in another.

Sorry if this is a silly question. Thanks for any input! all (knowledgable) input welcome!

Comment: I think you mean $\land$ not $\lor$ in the displayed formula (and I don't see what value the formula adds). Results of point set topology don't depend on any measure. A topology determines a $\sigma$-algebra, but not a measure: the real line $\Bbb{R}$ and the unit interval $(0, 1)$ are homeomorphic, but the standard measures on those sets are not the same. It doesn't make much sense to ask "does the XYZ theorem hold if we change the topology|".

Comment: thanks fixed that!

Comment: thanks I needed that clarified, I know that homeomorphisms do not preserve measure. So measurable functions preserve topological properties? No, right?

Comment: They usually don't no.

Comment: thanks! so if a property is topologically invariant it need not be measure-invariant (loss for term here)?

Comment: Functions that preserve measure in the sense that $\mu(f[X]) = \mu(X)$ can't be expected to preserve any topological properties (you can't just ignore sets of measure 0 in topology).

Comment: but you could though right? Like two closed intervals or both open intervals of same length. They are certainly homeomorphic but this is not always the case is what you're saying, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often we start even with just a set $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{S}$ on $X$, and the combo is called a *measurable space*. The members of $\mathcal{S}$ are called (plain) measurable. If we actually then define a function $\mu$ on this $\mathcal{S}$ (with codomain $\Bbb R$ or the extended reals or complex numbers or vectors, depending on what type of measure theory you want, obeying additivity etc.), the combination $(X,\mu, \mathcal{S})$ is called a *measure space*. (One could consider different measures on the same measurable space, or even the space of all measures on the measurable space, and study *its* structure etc.)

If we have a topology given, like on $\Bbb R$, the default measurable space will often be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology (or open sets, or the intervals etc.) and people are mostly interested in Borel measures defined on it. For the Reals the notion of a Lebesgue-measurable subset is much more general than just being a Borel set: it's initially only defined for Borel sets but the Carathéodory construction allows us to extend it to a larger $\sigma$-algebra: we can add null sets too and mix those in. So $\mu$-measurable set sometimes means more than just a member of the original measurable space. Many, but not all, classic theorems are indeed typical for Euclidean spaces with the standard topology, Borel sets and Lebesgue-measurable sets, or at least most often used there.

Comment: by "plain" measurable do you mean they only have an outer measure using the infimum definition?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame No. We have no measure yet. Just a member of the $\sigma$-algebra is called measurable, no more.

Comment: got it thanks, sort of like in topology we just call them $\textit{open}$ thats all nothing more.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame precisely.

Comment: I tried looking for your email to thank you, but thanks so much! for your continued contributions to both my questions and others, I often see your responses and you always find a way to help me out in exactly what I need!

Comment: @HossienSahebjame I'm glad I could help..